# OpenGL - Local Up and Right From Matrix 4x4?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, quaternions, glm-math

I have a transform matrix 4x4 built in the following way:

```
glm::mat4 matrix;
glm::quat orientation = toQuaternion(rotation);
matrix*= glm::mat4_cast(orientation);
matrix= glm::translate(matrix, position);
matrix= glm::scale(matrix, scale);

orientation = toQuaternion(localRotation);
matrix*= glm::mat4_cast(orientation);
matrix= glm::scale(matrix, localScale);
```

where rotation, position, scale, localRotation, and localScale are all vector3's. As per the advice of many different questions on many different forums, it *should* be possible to fish local directions out of the resulting matrix like so:

```
right   = glm::vec3(matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2]);
up      = glm::vec3(matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2]);
forward = glm::vec3(matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2]);
```

where all these directions are normalized. I then use these directions to get a view matrix like so:

```
glm::lookAt(position, position + forward, up);
```

It all works great - EXCEPT: when I'm flying around a scene, the right and up vectors are totally erroneous. The forward direction is always exactly as it should be. When I'm at 0, 0, -1 looking at 0,0,0, all the directions are correct. But when I look in different directions (except for the inverse of looking at the origin from 0,0,-1), right and up are inconsistent. They aren't world vectors, nor are they local vectors. They seem to be almost random. Where am I going wrong? How can I get consistent local up and local right vectors from the 4x4 transform matrix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`matrix` is a local-to-world transformation, whereas a view matrix is world-to-local, which means that in this case `matrix` is the *inverse* of the view matrix. The code you currently have only works for a view matrix. Simply exchange the rows and columns:

```
right   = glm::vec3(matrix[0][0], matrix[1][0], matrix[2][0]);
up      = glm::vec3(matrix[0][1], matrix[1][1], matrix[2][1]);
forward = glm::vec3(matrix[0][2], matrix[1][2], matrix[2][2]);
```

A possible reason that it works for `(0, -1, 0)` is because the rotation/scaling part of the view matrix looks like:

```
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

The corresponding part of `matrix` is the inverse of the above, which is of course identical. Try it with another direction.

Comment: Wow! This DID fix up/down! However, the same problem exists for left/right.

Comment: @Skarab could it be a sign problem? What if you take the minus of the first column as `right`; if the "rotation part" is orthogonal (as it should be), and both `up` and `forward` are correct, then `right` *must* be either + or - the correct value (depending on coordinate handed-ness convention).

Comment: I'll be damned, that was it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU ROCK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I've been stuck on this problem for over a week now, I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you just broke a two day deadlock for me.